# History of Mathematical Notation

Tags: ho.history-overview

I would like to see a simple example which shows how mathematical notation were evolve in time and space.

Say, consider the formula
$$(x+2)^2=x^2+4{\cdot}x+4.$$
If I understand correctly, Franciscus Vieta would write something like this. (Feel free to correct me.)

### $\overline{N+2}$ quadr. æqualia $Q+N\,4+4$.

($N$ stays for unknown and $Q$ for its square.)

Can you give me the other examples?

Comment: perhaps you might want to focus the question, in particular, to what extent is it not answered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematical_notation

Comment: @CarloBeenakker No, Wikipedia article does not contain the answer. And example like that would be helpful for me and others. I hope that there are people here on MO who could answer.

Comment: Too broad as MO question. I think there is a consensus about the history of the use of letters in mathematics. Apart from that, each single notation has its own history. Which of these have you  in mind?

Comment: @AmirAsghari I would like to see the evolution of one formula to see big picture. (Maybe the choice $(x+2)^2=x^2+4{\cdot}x+4$ is not optimal.)

Comment: Maybe Joseph Mazur's book *Enlightening Symbols* has an example of what you want? http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10204.html

Comment: This question may also be a good fit for [hsm.se].

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For a quite extensive overview with many examples, you might want to check out [The origins and development of mathematical notation](http://math.unipa.it/~grim/mathnotation.pdf).
I also enjoyed reading Stephen Wolfram's take on [Mathematical Notation – past and future,](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/mathematical-notation-past-future/) with a great variety of illustrations.

---

The OP asks specifically for the evolution of one formula, "to see the big picture". Here is one example, taken from [Math through the ages](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Math_Through_the_Ages.html?id=JAXNVaPt7uQC&redir_esc=y):

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I think that the most complete source is still :

- [Florian Cajori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florian_Cajori) (1859-1939), [A History of Mathematical Notations](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1928 - Dover reprint).

We can easily find there examples regarding the evolution of "algebraic" symbolism through the modern era :

- §122 [page 90](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA90) : [Leonardo Piasano (Fibonacci)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) (c.1170 – c.1250), from [Liber abaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Abaci)
- §130 [page 101](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA101) : [Nicolas Chuquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Chuquet) (c.1445 – c.1488), from [Triparty en la science des nombres](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triparty_en_la_science_des_nombres)
- §132 [page 103](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA103) : [Estienne de La Roche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estienne_de_La_Roche) (1470–1530), from *L'Arismetique* (1520)
- §134-on [page 106](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA106) : [Luca Pacioli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luca_Pacioli) (c.1447–1517), from [Summa de arithmetica, geometria, proportioni et proportionalita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summa_de_arithmetica) (1494)
- §140 [page 117](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA117) : [Gerolamo Cardano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano) (1501 – 1576) ), from [Artis Magnæ, Sive de Regulis Algebraicis Liber Unus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Magna_(Gerolamo_Cardano)) (1545)
- §151 [page 139](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA139) : [Michael Stifel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Stifel)  (1487 – 1567), from *Arithmetica integra* (1544)
- §162 [page 154](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA156) : [Simon Stevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin)  (1548 – 1620), from [De Thiende](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Thiende) ('the art of tenths'), first published in Dutch in 1585 and translated into French as *Disme*
- §170 [page 169](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA170) : [Leonard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Digges_(scientist)) (c.1515–c.1559) and [Thomas Digges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Digges)  (c.1546 – 1595) , from *An Arithmetical Warlike Treatise Named Stratioticos* (1579)
- §176 [page 181](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA181) : [François Viète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Vi%C3%A8te)  (1540 – 1603), from [Zeteticorum libri quinque](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeteticorum_libri_quinque) (1591)
- §191 [page 205](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA207) : [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) (1596 - 1650), from [La Géométrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie) (1637).

Answer (score 5):

"The big picture" that can be seen in Carlo Beenakker's [example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/224730/29316) is

> > Rhetorical (verbal);   Syncopated  (abbreviated words);       Symbolic.

However, this well-known picture is very algebra-oriented and does not say anything about the use of notations in say geometry as discussed here "
[The Shaping of Deduction in Greek Mathematics: A Study in Cognitive History](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/history-mathematics/shaping-deduction-greek-mathematics-study-cognitive-history)
" or as asked here [Uppercase Point Labels in High-School Diagrams](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28758/29316). 
Thus, at least for me, the interesting answers to OP questions would be those that are not related to algebra.

Comment: As an instance of the picture,  the letter "e" in "et" for addition was wasted while "t" evolved to the symbol "+".

Comment: @PietroMajer what a beautiful bit of history :)

Comment: @PietroMajer, do you have evidence for this? Algebra was developed in Italian, where the word is just "e" and the "t" from Latin had been wasted.

Comment: According to Florian Cajori, the mathematical symbol + came into use in Germany,  between 1450-1480. He mentions a number of manuscripts in Latin from the Dresden Library were both "+" and "et" are used somehow interchangeably both in arithmetic and grammatical use. 
On the grammatical side, short forms are well-known in paleography. J.L.Walthers listes 102 different forms  for the conjunction "et", including "+".

Answer (score 3):

You might also enjoy [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Operation](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html)!!

Answer (score 3):

> Find a quantity such that $\varsigma\;\overline{\beta}$ squared equals
>   $$\Delta^{\Upsilon}\;\varsigma\overline{\delta}\;{\stackrel{o}{M}}\overline{\delta}$$

(My translation into English from Diophantes $\alpha\rho\iota\theta\mu\eta\tau\iota\kappa\eta$.)